# my hard disk works very slow

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have a Seagate 500 GB Hard disk which was working fine for a year. The Hard disk is powered by USB cable. It had 120 GB memory of free space. Now when I connect my HD, my windows keeps loading it and all I can see is the Hard disk symbol in 'My computer' screen without my Hard disk name in it ( Normally it used to show my HD name and available memory in it but now its just Disk symbol ) and I am unable to access it as the windows is loading infinitely. :(

I tried running chkdsk \F and \R but nothing happening.

Could Some one please suggest me a solution. I have very important data in it :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably your HD has some problem, physical problem, first you should try it in another computer, if it works there then immediately back up your data just in case and then run a chkdsk to see if there is any problem, if it doesnt work on another computer either then the problem is more serious, you should try to change the cable as this might be the problem as well, if it still doesnt work then move onto disk recovery software like  [testdisk](http://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk) it will be able to read on your partitions and try to fix them or recover any data that was on the drive.

All of this is assuming your disk is still rescue-able, you might have dropped it and damaged it internally thats why Windows cant even read the name of the label of your drive, try the solutions above and pray for the best, hard drives are so delicate, you should consider buying an ssd and moving your sensitive data to it as they have no moving parts and are more durable.